# Blade view not fetching data from controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

In my controller, I'm getting some values from the database and sending them to Blade View.  I checked my query through `php artisan tinker`, and it returns a valid record. The issue is that my Blade view is not fetching values passed from the controller.

**Controller**

```
public function getMake()
{
    $records = DB::table('users')->get()->toArray();

    return view('products.qrcodes.basic',compact('records'));
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/basicfile', 'niceActionController@getMake');
```

**View**

```
<select>
  <option selected disabled>Make*</option>
   @if(empty($records))
      Whoops! Something went wrong
   @else
   @foreach ($records as $key => $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
   @endif
</select>
```

Comment: if you're getting `Whoops! Something went wrong` then your `$records` are simply empty you can confirm that with `dd($records)`

Comment: @N69S I' m getting nothing. Neither Whoops nor any record. 
I checked my query into tinker and it's working perfectly

Comment: @N69S When I did dd($records). Nothing happens or show on page.

Comment: @Shaan Why are you converting a collection to array?

Comment: `<option value="{{ $item['id'] }}">{{ $item['name'] }}</option>` if you are converting collection into array then you can access this way.

Comment: @Rob
I changed it to $records =  DB::table('users')->get(); still no luck

Comment: @AkhtarMunir No luck, still no any data ....

Comment: @Shaan can you dd $records before you return view

Comment: @Shaan What are you getting in `dd($records)`?

Comment: are you redirecting to the exact page, to which you are passing the data ?

Comment: @DinoNumić dd($records); shows nothing on basic.blade page

Comment: @Rob it returns nothing on basic.blade view

Comment: @AkhtarMunir Yes, it's redirecting on the same page (basic.blade)

Comment: when you `dd($records);` inside controller before returing to view, what it gives ?

Comment: Add `dd($records)` in controller before returning view and add a die there as well. `dd($records);die;`.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it should work :

```
public function getMake()
{
  $records = DB::table('users')->get();
  return view('products.qrcodes.basic',compact('records'));
}
```

Blade :

```
<select>
  <option selected>Make*</option>
   @if(empty($records))
     <p>No records Found</p>
   @else
   @foreach ($records as $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
   @endif
</select>
```

Comment: No luck bro. Still no data.

Comment: Are you sure your `$records` has a `key` and  a `value` ? and your `value` has an array?

Comment: As i already mentioned that If I check my query into PHP tinker, it shows the array with values.

Comment: @Shaan arry!!! this one > `<option value="{{ $item['id'] }}">{{ $item['name'] }}</option>` any luck?

Answer (score 1):

**niceActionController**

```
public function getMake()
{
  $records = DB::table('users')->get();
  return view('products.qrcodes.basic',compact('records'));
}
```

**basic.blade.php**

```
<select>
  <option selected>Make*</option>
   @if(empty($records))
     <p>No records Found</p>
   @else
   @foreach ($records as $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
   @endif
</select>
```

Comment: @Visak Katariya 
Still no any results.. :(

Comment: @Visak Katariya 
Thanks for your support. Please read my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my route file. In route, I had defined another route which was calling the same Blade View I was working on.

So maybe it was a conflict there. I simply removed that route and It worked!

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert collection to array, you can work with your data right after `->get()`, like this:
`DB::table('users')->get();`